# Sections unable to be inline

Tags: html, css

```css
header {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  color: grey;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Cambria;
  font-size: 30pt;
  color: darkgrey;
  padding: 25px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

main {
  height: 600px;
}

main table {
  caption-side: top;
  font-family: Cambria;
  font-size: 18pt;
  font-weight: bold;
}

section {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 50px 0;
}

td.tede {
  padding: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  border: double 5px grey;
}

table.pierlewagora {
  caption-side: top;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: cyan;
  empty-cells: hide;
}

table.pierprawagora {
  caption-side: bottom;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: magenta;
  empty-cells: show;
}

table.pierlewadol {
  caption-side: bottom;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: yellow;
  empty-cells: show;
}

table.pierprawadol {
  caption-side: bottom;
  text-align: right;
  background-image: url('pliki_zrodlowe/matrix.jpg');
  empty-cells: hide;
}

table.pierprawadol::after {
  clear: both;
}

table.szesc {
  border: 20px groove;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table.szesc td {
  border: solid 5px lightblue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

table.siedem {
  border: 20px ridge;
  border-collapse: separate;
  padding: 20px 50px;
}

table.siedem td {
  border: solid 5px darkblue;
}

table.siedem td p {
  margin: 0;
}

footer {
  background-color: darkgrey;
  padding: 50px;
  height: 400px;
  clear: both;
}

footer table {
  width: 100%
}

footer table td {
  width: 50%;
}

img.lewa {
  min-width: 300px;
  min-height: 300px;
}

img.prawa {
  max-width: 100px;
  max-height: 120px;
}

caption:first-of-type {
  text-align: left;
}

caption.eeeeee {
  text-align: right;
}

caption:last-of-type {
  text-align: left;
}

table.szesc>caption {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!doctype HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link href="cssdata.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Jakub - Ćwiczenie 18 (17)</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Tablele i wymiary - k</h1>
  </header>
  <main>
    <table>
      <caption>Tabela z grafiką w części głównej</caption>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <img src="pliki_zrodlowe\obrazek1.jpg" alt="zdj">
        </td>
        <td>
          <img src="pliki_zrodlowe\obrazek2.jpg" alt="zdj">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <img src="pliki_zrodlowe\obrazek3.jpg" alt="zdj">
        </td>
        <td>
          <img src="pliki_zrodlowe\obrazek4.jpg" alt="zdj">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </main>
  <section>
    <table class="pierlewagora">
      <caption>tabela z góry lewa</caption>
      <tr>
        <td class="tede">
          <p>Komórka 1</p>
        </td>
        <td class="tede">

        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="tede">
          <p>Komórka 3</p>
        </td>
        <td class="tede">
          <p>Komórka 4</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </section>
  <section>
    <table class="pierprawagora">
      <caption class="eeeeee" style="text-align: right">tabela z góry prawa</caption>
      <tr>
        <td class="tede">
          <p>Komórka 1</p>
        </td>
        <td class="tede">
          <p>Komórka 2</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="tede">

        </td>
        <td class="tede">
          <p>Komórka 4</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </section>
  <section>
    <table class="pierlewadol">
      <caption>tabela z dolna lewa</caption>
      <tr>
        <td class="tede">

        </td>
        <td class="tede">
          <p>Komórka 2</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="tede">
          <p>Komórka 3</p>
        </td>
        <td class="tede">
          <p>Komórka 4</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </section>
  <section>
    <table class="pierprawadol">
      <tr>
        <td class="tede">
          <p>Komórka 1</p>
        </td>
        <td class="tede">
          <p>Komórka 2</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="tede">
          <p>Komórka 3</p>
        </td>
        <td class="tede">

        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </section>
  <section>
    <table class="szesc">
      <caption>Tabela 6</caption>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>Komórka 1 Komórka 1</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Komórka 2 Komórka 2</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>Komórka 3</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Komórka 4</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </section>
  <section>
    <table class="siedem">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>Komórka 1</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Komórka 2</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>Komórka 3</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>Komórka 4</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </section>
  <footer>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <img class="lewa" src="pliki_zrodlowe/obrazek7.jpg">
        </td>
        <td>
          <img class="prawa" src="pliki_zrodlowe/obrazek8.jpg">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Table 6 should be inline with table 7. for some reason, table 6 sticks to the right and wreaks the doc. This gave me 7 anxieties, rendering me unable to diagnose the problem. Any clue why?

There is supposedly nothing blocking them from displaying as intended. 3 of my friends have checked it already, to find no issue.

Comment: Don't use float for alignment, take a look to flexbox or grid

Comment: It was ordered in the assignment of mine @Sfili_81

Comment: Your section containing the third table is higher than the one containing the fourth - so the 6th table section (your numbering is weird, btw.) is _allowed_ to float into that space below the fourth. You will need to put a `clear: left` onto that 6th section.

Comment: @CBroe why is it? Is a certain CSS element responsible for this?

Comment: Your third/yellow table has a `caption`, and therefor it is a bit higher than the fourth, which doesn't have one ...